# In Abaqus, what is meant by "Second-order accuracy" using Linear Explicit Hexahedral elements?

Tags: abaqus

When using a **Linear** *Explicit* *Hexahedral* 3D stress element in Abaqus, what is meant by the element controls option:  **second-order accurate formulation**?

I understand that the reduced integration is changing the number of gauss points from eight to one using this 3D element, but I'm unclear what this second-order accurate formulation means.

Is that specifically referring to numerical round-off, i.e. the number of decimal points used in the calculation, i.e. (0.42356789 vs 0.423)?  Or is this referring to the gauss points separately, i.e. (x=0.0000, w=2.0000 vs. x=0.0, w=2.0) used in the quadrature integration?

[image]